# How can I make an SQL Server 2008 procedure get data from SQL Server Compact?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

How can I transfer a SQL Server Compact database to SQL Server 2008 by using 
a SQL Server 2008 procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a SQLCLR procedure using the SQL Server Compact OLEDB provider. I have some sample code here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2008/10/accessing-sql-compact-from-sql-server.html
If you want to do a one off transfer from SQL Server Compact to SQL Server 2008, you can use my ExportSqlCe command line to in combination with sqlcmd to transfer the entire database

Comment: THX for the answer but i want to transfer data base from SQL compact to SQL server 2008  and edit it   I want some think like translator

Comment: sorry its my first answer and mt English not very well